# Check if an element exists in a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have a set of radio buttons, when a radio button is selected the element is pushed into an object.

Then I need to take the value of the elements in the object and then push them into an array, if they are not already in the array.

My problem is that I keep getting duplicates or more in my array of each of the values with this function because I am not checking correctly if they exists.

How can I check if the element already exists in my array and then exclude it from being added?

```
      _this.selected = {};
      _this.selectedArray = [];

      //loop through the object
      angular.forEach(_this.selected, function ( item ){

        //if it is not the first time the array is getting data loop through the array
        if(_this.selectedArray.length > 0) {
          _this.selectedArray.forEach(function (node){

            //check to see if the item already exists-- this is where it is failing
            //and running the loop too many times 
            if(node.id !== item.id){
              _this.selectedArray.push(item);
            }
          });
        } else {
          _this.selectedArray.push(share);
        }
      });
```

Comment: "is pushed into an object" How? What do you mean by "push into an object"? :)

Comment: I meant the object is updates with the key, value pair.

Comment: Are you using id as a key? If yes then how could there be duplicates?

Comment: is `node` an element, or an object.

Comment: 'node' is an object, they are both objects and I am comparing the id of each object.

Comment: Then any solution that uses indexOf isn't going to work, because one object is never equal to another unless it literally is the same object. `{} === {}` is false.

Comment: Looks like your only solution is to loop over each object looking for an existing.

Comment: Can you please clarify your title? It's asking for something that is very different from what you are looking for. You are looking to check if an object exists in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use additional hash to check if you have already added item to array.

```
  _this.selected = {};
  _this.selectedArray = [];
  _this.selectedHash = {};

  //loop through the object
  angular.forEach(_this.selected, function ( item ){
      if(_this.selectedHash[item.id]) { return; }

      _this.selectedArray.push(item);
      _this.selectedHash[item.id] = 1;         
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery's `inArray`? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray

It works the same as the `indexOf` method on `String`.

You could try `if $.inArray(node, selectedArray) == -1 // element is not in the array`

Comment: It's possible that he has jQuery, but probably unlikely since he's using angularjs.

Comment: I would have thought someone using Angular would be very likely to also be using jQuery.

Comment: well, considering that the whole point around angular is for your javascript to not directly interact with the dom, jquery becomes quite useless with angularjs (aside from a few helper methods such as this one)

Comment: This solution won't work anyway since he's using objects, according to his comments. back to the drawing board, :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run this function on that array to reduce it to unique values rather than applying complex code to check whether the array had an element or not

```
var getOnlyUniqueValuesInArray = function(arrayObj) {
    return arrayObj.reduce(function(a, b) {
        if (a.indexOf(b) < 0) a.push(b);
        return p;
    }, []);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi that should helps

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){


var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  _this.selected = {};
  _this.selectedArray = [];

  //loop through the object
  angular.forEach(_this.selected, function(item) {

    //if it is not the first time the array is getting data loop through the array
    if (_this.selectedArray.length > 0) {

      var canAdd = true;
      _this.selectedArray.forEach(function(node) {

        //do not add iny any of node.id will be equal to item.id
        if (node.id == item.id) {
          canAdd = false;
        }

      });
      if(canAdd){
        _this.selectedArray.push(item);
      };
    } else {
      _this.selectedArray.push(share);
    }
  });

})

});
```

Comment: You are not using `canAdd`.

Comment: No problem. BTW this still won't work for other reasons. To begin with: you are changing `selectedArray` while iterating over it.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko if(canAdd).. should be after loop block, not inside. I've updated answer

Comment: Will work now. And the last suggestion: since you are using native `forEach` it looks like `some` or `every` suits better when you need to check array elements against some predicate. `!selectedArray.some(function(node) {return node.id == item.id;})` or `selectedArray.every(function(node) {return node.id != item.id;})` :)